# Azure: Не могу создать SAS для блоб ресурса

Tags: perl, blob, azure-storage

Не могу создать shared access signature для блоб ресурса в азуре. По майкрософтовским документам строка от которой вычисляется хеш должна быть такакя:

> StringToSign = signedpermissions + "\n" +   signedstart + "\n" +
>   signedexpiry + "\n" +   canonicalizedresource + "\n" +
>   signedidentifier + "\n" +   signedIP + "\n" +   signedProtocol + "\n"
>   +   signedversion + "\n" +   signedResource + "\n" +  signedSnapshotTime + "\n" + rscc + "\n" +   rscd + "\n" +   rsce +
>   "\n" +   rscl + "\n" +   rsct

Мой ресурс имеет адрес "https://ribdkstoragepoc.blob.core.windows.net/project-poc/foo/koteyka.jpg". Я вычислил значения для актуальных переменных, остальные просто пустые строки:
signedpermissions = 'r'

signedexpiry = '2020-01-30T08:00:00Z'

canonicalizedresource = '/blob/ribdkstoragepoc/project-poc/foo/koteyka.jpg'

signedresource = 'b'

signedversion = '2018-03-28'

Остальные, как я и писал, пустые строки. Далее, у меня есть ключ которым я подписываю запросы. Он правильный - проверено. Генерирую подпись:

my $sig = Digest::SHA::hmac_sha256_base64($stringToSign, $key);

Конечный урл выглядит так: https://ribdkstoragepoc.blob.core.windows.net/project-poc/foo/koteyka.jpg?sig=MgAFDDO0mPpOzuD4AFgwPSlAnm5xYgBObS5cuXRed3g&se=2020-01-30T08%3A00%3A00Z&sv=2018-03-28&sp=r&sr=b

Азура возвращает ошибку: Signature fields not well formed.

Что я не так делаю? Буду очень рад помощи! Или может быть кто-то поделится рабочим примером формирования SAS на любом языке чтоб я мог сравнить результаты?

Comment: А вот тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas написано, что метод формирования строки для подписи, который вы тут указали действует с версии 2018-11-09. А у вы передаете более раннюю версию ...

Comment: Mike, я попробовал версию '2019-02-02'. Она у меня работает когда я подписываю http запросы в азуру. А вот SAS опять не принимается. Видимо причина еще в чем либо...